# how to create tokens from CFG

Tags: context-free, compilers

i have a context free grammar

i  want to create a tokens from the language

is there any techniques to do that ?

for example , this CFG from Prof.Alex Aiken notes :

```
 D -> D ; P | D

 D -> def id(ARGS) = E ; 
 ARGS -> id, ARGS | id
 E -> int | id | if E1 = E2 then E3 else E4 | E1 + E2 | E1 - E2 | id(E1,...,En)
```

how can i crate the tokens ?

the professor explain how i do that in some inputs

for example , if i have the input :

```
x = 10
```

then i have

```
<id.,x> < opp., = > ......
```

but how i can do that from the CFG

thank you All

Comment: A variety of parsing algorithms for context-free grammars can be found in literature. Why not apply one of them?

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of ways of parsing CFGs into tokens and there are many resources covering these. We expect askers to do some basic research before asking here and a good answer to your question would essentially be a whole textbook, which is far too much to ask for. I suggest that you look at some of the resources on parsing and we'll be happy to help with any more specific questions that you might have.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of creating a parse tree given a grammar and a word generated by it is known as *parsing*. The [CYK algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) parses all context-free grammars, but is slow. In practice, only restricted types of context-free grammars are used, and these can be parsed in linear time. The common example is [LALR parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser). Perhaps you will learn more about this topic in due time.